# Activate the catalog sidebar in Prestashop for every category

Tags: configuration, prestashop

How I can activate the Prestashop catalog sidebar for all categories?  The catalog sidebar lets users can refine their search by pricing, fabric, or other options.

It only works for me with the demo categories that were made when installing Prestashop.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@yenshirak has answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659916/activate-catalog-in-prestashop-on-every-category) previously over on StackOverflow:

> 1. In the PrestaShop back-office go to `Modules` -> `Modules`
> 2. Find the `Layered navigation block` and click `Configure`
> 3. Find the filter template and click `Edit`
> 4. Select new categories in `Categories used for this template`
> 5. Click `Save`
> 6. Click `Rebuild entire price index`
> 7. Click `Build attribute index`
> 8. Click `Build URL index`